# Google cloud - get current time offset from UTC of timezone (when timezone is described using Supported Time Zone Value)

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore, timezone-offset, gql, trifacta

I'm including timezone identifiers as strings, in data that's being stored in Google Cloud DataStore, and I want to get the *current* time offset from UTC (including any adjustment for daylight saving time), for that timezone identifier. For example I want to return something like `-08:00`, or `+6:00`

The identifiers I'm using are the ([Supported Time Zone Values](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Supported-Time-Zone-Values_66194188)) (these appear to be timezone identifiers defined by [Trifacta](https://www.trifacta.com/partners/google/), which is a partner of Google that provides data prep capabilities) - the Google documentation appears to be a dupe of Trifacta's own documentation - https://docs.trifacta.com/display/SS/Supported+Time+Zone+Values.

The Google documentation says this in relation to the Supported Time Zone Values:

> For the functions that support use of specified time zones, you can
>   apply the [Supported Time Zone Values] as parameters to specify the time
>   zone

So, I'm wondering if there might be functions (either in Java, or in GQL) that will accept a Supported Time Zone Value and return an offset, or allow it to be derived? For example I'm wondering if there's something available in Trifacta or GQL that's like the `AT TIME ZONE` in SQL Server 2016.

How can I return the current offset to UTC based on the Supported Time Zone Value?

Answer (score 0):

The only GCP product that uses the Supported Time Zone Values afaik is Cloud Dataprep by Trifacta. The time zone values are taken by functions [NOW](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/NOW-Function_66194061#str_timezone) and [TODAY](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/TODAY-Function_66194062#str_timezone). In java, you can take a look at [ZoneOffset class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html), but I'm not sure if you can incorporate all the identifiers form Trifacta.

Comment: If this answer was helpful, could you accept it? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

if I understand correctly you are trying to modify most current dates at your timezone based on an offset. This is achievable with the combination of functions using NOW and DATADD in Trifacta.

Refer the article here to get more clarity on this https://community.trifacta.com/s/article/Function-NOW-DATEADD-and-DATEDIF

Best
Vardan

Comment: Thanks Vardan but no, you need to read the question more carefully to understand what I'm asking